# Connection Java - MySQL : Public Key Retrieval is not allowed

Tags: java, mysql, exception, connector

I try to connect MySQL database with Java using connector 8.0.11.   Everything seems to be OK, but I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed at
     com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:108) at 
     com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:95) at
     com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) at     
     com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:862) at 
     com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:444) at
     com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:230) at
     com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:226) at
     com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:438) at
     com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:146) at
     com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:119) at
     ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:28) at
     Main.main(Main.java:8)
```

Here is my Connection Manager class:

```
public class ConnectionManager {

    public static final String serverTimeZone = "UTC";
    public static final String serverName = "localhost";
    public static final String databaseName ="biblioteka";
    public static final int portNumber = 3306;
    public static final String user = "anyroot";
    public static final String password = "anyroot";
    
    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    
        MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
    
        dataSource.setUseSSL( false );
        dataSource.setServerTimezone( serverTimeZone );
        dataSource.setServerName( serverName );
        dataSource.setDatabaseName( databaseName );
        dataSource.setPortNumber( portNumber );
        dataSource.setUser( user );
        dataSource.setPassword( password );
        
        return dataSource.getConnection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide some code: how are you trying to connect. Stack trace of the exception would be helpful as well.

Comment: For connectrion need add to dburl : allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true

Answer (score 822, accepted):

You should add client option to your mysql-connector `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` to allow the client to automatically request the public key from the server. Note that `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=True` could allow a malicious proxy to perform a MITM attack to get the plaintext password, so it is False by default and must be explicitly enabled.

See [MySQL .NET Connection String Options](https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/connection-options/)

you could also try adding `useSSL=false` when you use it for testing/develop purposes

example:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
```

Comment: Well, this worked for me but I am not sure how legit these options are from security perspective.

Comment: `useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` is what I needed only when I tried connecting from `docker_container1` to `docker_container2_mysql(where mysql is installed)` within my local host. While from my host machine to `docker_container2_mysql`, `useSSL=false` is enough.

Comment: allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&amp;useSSL=false  , tank you it works

Comment: Can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: Adding 'allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true' to my JDBC connection string solved my development system's issue after a Windows 10 update yesterday. Guess Microsoft plugged another hole, and the option should be used "for development only" in my view, where SSL is not turned on.

Comment: My problem is, it was working fine till yesterday. What could have changed overnight?

Comment: try removing useSSl=false from the url it worked for me

Comment: I was struggling making `dbeaver` connect to *dockerized* `mysql-8` server. `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` did the trick for me :+1:

Comment: @SandeepKumar Same thing happened to me. Did you figure out why? And yes, I know a lot of time passed after you commented this, so I don't have high expectations :)

Comment: How to do this in commandline? For example I am dumping a file or querying via commandline?

Comment: with `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` it works for me, thnx

Comment: Had the same issue using spring and it worked :)

Comment: What's the equivalent of this when using mysql in nodejs please?

Answer (score 631):

For **DBeaver** users:

1. Right-click your connection, choose "Edit Connection"
2. On the "Connection settings" screen (main screen), click on "Edit Driver Settings"
3. Click on "Driver properties"
4. Set these two properties: "allowPublicKeyRetrieval" to `true` and "useSSL" to `false`

Comment: For me, modifying just the "allowPublicKeyRetrieval" field under "Driver Properties" from False to True did the trick. May I ask why add the "useSSL" property and then set it to False? (I too am using DBeaver)

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, I had a heck of a time figuring out how to set the value because visually it did not show anything that looked like input was expected or being recorded. I had to double click the value column and trust that it was taking input before hitting enter or clicking out of it and only then did the value I typed in show up.

Comment: Is enough set both properties in the `Driver properties` section/tab

Comment: Trying to connect to an out-of-the-box mysql install on a docker container. Doing this made it work so I can connect to the mysql db using dbeaver.

Comment: This was the correct answer in my case when using DBeaver client

Comment: In my case "allowPublicKeyRetrieval" properties only accept 'TRUE' (capital latter)

Comment: Works for `localhost` database with dbeaver. Thank you

Comment: As a DBeaver user, I tried all the options suggested here. But, I still getting the Deinal. DBeaver 23.1.0.202306041918. MySQL Server version: 8.0.33 MySQL Community Server - GPL.

Answer (score 84):

When doing this from **DBeaver** I had to go to "Connection settings" -> "SSL" tab and then :

- uncheck the "Verify server certificate"
- check the "Allow public key retrival"

This is how it looks like.
[image: DBeaver configuration]

Note that this is suitable for local development only.

Comment: this is what worked for me on the latest version of DB Beaver

Comment: Great. It worked with DBeaver version 21.0.4

Comment: this solved my problem

Comment: This should be the answer for DBeaver users.

Comment: The main interest is that it seems the SSL option is even required for a `127.0.0.1:3036` local plain SSH tunneled connection.

Comment: for DBeaver 21.3 this one worked for me without the need to change connection string ...

Comment: It's works me for localhost connection

Answer (score 53):

Use  `jdbc url` as :

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Database_dbName?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=False;
```

**`PortNo: 3306` can be different in your configuation**

Comment: A small correction here.
The connection property 'useSSL' acceptable values are: 'TRUE', 'FALSE', 'YES' or 'NO'. The value 'false;' is not acceptable.

Comment: @bluelurker I have updated it.

Answer (score 30):

Alternatively to the suggested answers you could try and use *mysql_native_password* authentication plugin instead of *caching_sha2_password* authentication plugin.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_password_here';
```

Comment: never use root to connect to the database from a program, bad practice.

Answer (score 23):

I updated this parameter when I faced the issue of "public-key-retrieval-is-not-allowed" with root account.

[image: DBeaver update this parameter]

Answer (score 20):

[image]

Open DBeaver->Edit connection->find driver properties->`allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` and `useSSl=true`

Answer (score 9):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
```

You can insert this line to your applications.properties file and this means,

- `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/` This one uses mysql as the database service. I think this can changed by using relavent name and the port of your database name.
- `database?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` = use the database named database if you haven't already make a database like that, make a new one.
- `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` = to allow the client to automatically request the public key from the server. (This part might be additional)
- `useSSL=false` = This will disable SSL and also suppress the SSL errors

Furthermore, be alert about the `spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect` property in the same file.

Finally check whether you've added following dependency in dependencies in your pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.23</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 8):

First of all, please make sure your Database server is up and running. 
I was getting the same error, after trying all the answers listed here I found out that my Database server was not running.

You can check the same from MySQL Workbench, or Command line using

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p
```

This sounds obvious, but many times we assume that Database server is up and running all the time, especially when we are working on our local machine, when we restart/shutdown the machine, Database server will be shutdown automatically.

Comment: I logged into mysql via terminal and tried again and it worked.

Answer (score 7):

I solve this issue using below configuration on spring boot framework

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db-name?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Comment: right, simplest could be your local mysql password is something different that what is configured in  application.properties .. go check and change that.
This was the case with mw

Answer (score 6):

This also can be happened due to wrong user name or password.
As solutions I've added  `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false` part but still I got error then I checked the password and it was wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Another way, on DBeaver.

You can edit the connection of a database, go to SSL tab in connection settings. There's a checkbox "allow public key retrieval" mark it as true. That'll sove the issue.

Answer (score 6):

In MySQL 8.0 the default authentication plugin was changed from mysql_native_password to caching_sha2_password.
See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password for more information about this change.

What that means is that in order to use caching_sha2_password the connection must do one of the following:

- use a secure connection (useSSL=true)
- use an unencrypted connection that supports password exchange using an RSA key pair (useSSL=false and additional configuration parameters - see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html)

You have a few options:

- ALTER the users to use the mysql_native_password plugin (like how it was doing historically and will also work with older clients / connections which don't support caching_sha2_password)
- useSSL=true
- useSSL=false and configure public key retrieval (this doesn't mean using allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true which would avoid the error - but defeats the objective of this extra security and is slow - it does mean using something like server-public-key-path to point to the client side copy of the public key)

Answer (score 4):

I managed to connect to MySQL using SSL through DBeaver with `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=false` and `useSSL=true` driver settings, which is preferred solution from security perspective, so I wanted to share my solution here.

To establish a successful SSL connection, you need to provide the correct paths to the certificates in your client (e.g., DBeaver).

MySQL generates the certificates by default, so you don't need to generate them manually.

They are located in the `/var/lib/mysql` directory.

This is from official MySQL documentation:

> Automatic SSL and RSA File Generation
>
> For MySQL distributions compiled using OpenSSL, the MySQL server has
> the capability of automatically generating missing SSL and RSA files
> at startup. The auto_generate_certs,
> sha256_password_auto_generate_rsa_keys, and
> caching_sha2_password_auto_generate_rsa_keys system variables control
> automatic generation of these files. These variables are enabled by
> default. They can be enabled at startup and inspected but not set at
> runtime.
>
> At startup, the server automatically generates server-side and
> client-side SSL certificate and key files in the data directory if the
> auto_generate_certs system variable is enabled, no SSL options other
> than --ssl are specified, and the server-side SSL files are missing
> from the data directory. These files enable encrypted client
> connections using SSL; see Section 6.3.1, “Configuring MySQL to Use
> Encrypted Connections”.

If you can't find the certificates there, it's likely that you have modified the default behavior of MySQL using system variables. In that case, please refer to the documentation to learn how to resolve this issue.

The required certificate files for SSL connection are as follows:

- CA Certificate: `/var/lib/mysql/ca.pem`
- Client Certificate: `/var/lib/mysql/client-cert.pem`
- Client Private Key: `/var/lib/mysql/client-key.pem`

By providing these paths in the SSL configuration of your client application, you should be able to connect to MySQL using SSL successfully.

I hope this helps others who might encounter similar SSL connection issues with MySQL and DBeaver.

[image]

P.S If you use Docker Image, you need to copy certificates and key from docker container to your local computer, so MySQL client (e.g DBeaver) could find them there.

Comment: This should be the selected answer. Thank you for showing us how to do this correctly

Answer (score 3):

The above error in my case was actually due to the wrong username and password.
Solving the issue:
1. Go to the line DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/?useSSL=false", "username", "password");
The fields username and password might be wrong. Enter the username and password which you use to start your mysql client. The username is generally root and password is the string which you enter when a screen similar to this appears [Startup screen of mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLfhY.png)

Note: The portname 3306 might be different in your case.

Answer (score 2):

I found this issue frustrating because I was able to interact with the database yesterday, but after coming back this morning, I started getting this error.

I tried adding the `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` flag, but I kept getting the error.

What fixed it for me was doing `Project->Clean` in Eclipse and `Clean` on my Tomcat server. One (or both) of those fixed it.

I don't understand why, because I build my project using Maven, and have been restarting my server after each code change. Very irritating...

Answer (score 2):

Update the useSSL=true in spring boot application connection with mysql;

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
```

Comment: Perfect - i had this error after server was upgraded to mysql 8 from mysql 5.
useSSL=true fixed the error

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for MacOS Sierra, and running MySQL version 8.0.11. Please make sure driver you have added in your build path - "add external jar" should match up with SQL version.

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/syscharacterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&rewriteBatchedStatements=true";
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was user error. I was using the `root` user with an invalid password. I am not sure why I didn't get an auth error but instead received this cryptic message.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the following error while connecting the mysql (either local or mysql container running the mysql):

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed

Solution:
Add the following line in your database service:

```
command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Answer (score 1):

For folks that are using a .xml file to store their database connection details, modifying your jdbcUrl to below should make your connection from your test tomcat server to your database valid again:

```
jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/DB_NAME?autoReconnect=true&amp;allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&amp;useSSL=false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Give connection URL as 
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hb_student_tracker?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC

Comment: how about in command line or connecting through commandline?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing such an issue while dockerizing our existing application. The solution si to add **allowPublicKeyRetrieval** connection option of MySQL with a value of **true** to the JDBC connection string.
If that is not working , try adding **useSSL** option to **false** as well .

The resultant string would look like this :

```
jdbc:mysql://<database server ip>:3306/databaseName?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
```

Answer (score 0):

---

> Setting `Server Time Zone` to my local place, fixed the issue.

---

[image: ServerTimeZone]

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in `pom.xml` (spring boot).
My pom.xml had two dependencies entries for different databases. Make sure to keep only the MySQL dependency and remove any other database dependency entry.

Answer (score 0):

check below line one more time

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customerbankdb?autoReconnect=true&AllowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false
```

Comment: the A must be lower case. "allowPublicKeyRetrieval"