# How to resolve Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' issue

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, maven, spring-boot

In eclipse when i started my application i got this - Could not discover the dialect to use. java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'.

> at java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load authentication plugin
>   'caching_sha2_password'.  at  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:868)     at  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:864)     at  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1746)
>     at  at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)    at  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2191)
>     at  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2222)
>     at  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2017)
>     at  at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:779)
>     at  at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
>     at  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at  at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>     at  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)    at
>     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:330)
>     at  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)     at  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)  at  at
>   ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionSource.java:54)
>     at  at
>   ch.qos.logback.core.db.ConnectionSourceBase.discoverConnectionProperties(ConnectionSourceBase.java:46)
>     at  at
>   ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource.start(DriverManagerConnectionSource.java:38)
>     at  at
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA.end(NestedComplexPropertyIA.java:161)
>     at  at
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.callEndAction(Interpreter.java:309)
>     at  at
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:193)
>     at  at
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter.endElement(Interpreter.java:179)
>     at  at
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.EventPlayer.play(EventPlayer.java:62)
>     at  at
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:165)
>     at  at
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:152)
>     at  at
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:110)
>     at  at
>   ch.qos.logback.core.joran.GenericConfigurator.doConfigure(GenericConfigurator.java:53)
>     at  at
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.configureByResource(ContextInitializer.java:75)
>     at  at
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextInitializer.autoConfig(ContextInitializer.java:150)
>     at  at
>   org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.init(StaticLoggerBinder.java:84)    at
>     at
>   org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.(StaticLoggerBinder.java:55)
>     at  at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:150)     at  at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:124)
>     at  at
>   org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:412)     at
>     at
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.util.StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.addStatus(StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.java:32)
>     at  at
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.util.StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.addInfo(StatusViaSLF4JLoggerFactory.java:20)
>     at  at
>   ch.qos.logback.classic.servlet.LogbackServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(LogbackServletContainerInitializer.java:32)
>     at  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245)
>     at  at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1421)
>     at  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1411)
>     at  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 205):

> Starting with MySQL 8.0.4, they have changed the default
>   authentication plugin for MySQL server from **mysql_native_password** to
>   **caching_sha2_password**.

You can run the below command to resolve the issue.

sample username / password => student / pass123

```
ALTER USER 'student'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'pass123';
```

Refer the official page for details: [MySQL Reference Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html)

Comment: Although this works, it is better to upgrade the MySQL Connector/J version (as suggested by some of the other answers) as that allows you to use the more secure sha2_caching authentication plugin.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes! I agree on that too.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel how?

Comment: @minseong You need to update MySQL Connector/J to at least 5.1.46, or - better - to 8.0.14.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel how do I do that? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54413365/unable-to-load-authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-even-when-mysql-co

Comment: @minseong By either updating the dependency in your Maven or Gradle dependency definition, or by manually downloading the newer version from the MySQL site and replacing it in the dependencies of your project.

Comment: did you see that ^^ question?

Comment: faced with `ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'user'@'localhost'
`

Comment: @Yusef Making a new user is not a good solution, but it works at least.

Answer (score 96):

Others have pointed to the root issue, but in my case I was using dbeaver and initially when setting up the mysql connection with dbeaver was selecting the wrong mysql driver (credit here for answer: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/4691#issuecomment-442173584 )

Selecting the MySQL choice in the below figure will give the error mentioned as the driver is mysql 4+ which can be seen in the database information tip.

---

[image: For this error selecting the top mysql 4+ choice in this figure will give the error mentioned in this quesiton]

---

Rather than selecting the MySQL driver instead select the MySQL 8+ driver, shown in the figure below.

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly my problem. Did you happen to then get another error: "Public Key Retrieval is not allowed"?

Comment: Interesting, no after the above, dbeaver loaded the tables.

Comment: THANK YOU. This helped me a lot. For those who are still getting the "Public Ket Retrieval is not allowed" error in DBeaver I found a link that solves this [here](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Confluence-questions/MySQL-Public-Key-Retrieval-is-not-allowed/qaq-p/778956).

Comment: `Public key retrieval is not allowed`

Comment: The people who got `Public Key Retrieval is not allowed`. Please, try rerun the program.

Comment: In DBeaver latest versions (checked with version 7.3) above two options available as "MySql 5" and "MySql". You have to choose  "MySql" and also when you hover your mouse over that option, it will show a hint saying that for mysql version 8+.

Comment: for "Public Key Retrieval is not allowed. " , just goto Driver properties in DBeaver and set allowPublicKeyRetrieval to "True", 

for non Dbeaver users, follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379839/connection-java-mysql-public-key-retrieval-is-not-allowed

Answer (score 64):

Upgrade your mysql-connector" lib package with your mysql version like below i am using 8.0.13 version and in pom I changed the version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <version>8.0.13</version>
</dependency>
```

My problem has resolved after this.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. For others, to find the latest version, please use this link; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java

Answer (score 34):

May be you are using wrong mysql_connector.

Use connector of same mysql version

Comment: Thanks. This works for me (on DBeaver, select `MySQL 8+` instead of `MySQL`) and I believe should be the right solution.

Answer (score 18):

I was hitting this error in one Spring Boot app, but not in another. Finally, I found the Spring Boot version in the one not working was 2.0.0.RELEASE and the one that was working was 2.0.1.RELEASE. That led to a difference in the MySQL Connector -- 5.1.45 vs. 5.1.46. I updated the Spring Boot version for the app that was throwing this error at startup and now it works.

Comment: This helped me!

Comment: Worked for me! I was using version 1.5.8.RELEASE.

Answer (score 18):

This could be your connectors for MySQL which need to be updated, as MySQL8 changed the encryption of passwords - so older connectors are encrypting them incorrectly.

The maven repo for the java connector can be found [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java).
**If you use flyway plugin**, you should also consider [updating it, too](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.flywaydb.flyway)!

Then you can simply update your *maven pom* with:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.17</version>
</dependency>
```

Or for others who use **Gradle**, you can update *build.gradle* with:

```
 buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
    }
    repositories {
        ...
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath('mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.11')
    }
 }
```

[image: All that you really need to do (build.gradle example)]

Answer (score 15):

You need just to delete your older connector and download new version (mysql-connector-java-5.1.46)

Comment: It worked. I wasted almost 2 days finding this solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

I am using mysql 8.0.12 and updating the mysql connector to mysql-connector-java-8.0.12 resolved the issue for me.

Hope it helps somebody.

Comment: Upgrade to at least 5.1.46 or the latest version like today we have 8.0.18. This will help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 9):

As Mentioned in above repilies:

**Starting with MySQL 8.0.4, the MySQL team changed the default authentication plugin for MySQL server from mysql_native_password to caching_sha2_password.**

So there are three ways to resolve this issue:

```
 1. drop USER 'user_name'@'localhost';
    flush privileges;
    CREATE USER 'user_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'user_name';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user_name'@'localhost';
    ALTER USER 'user_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 
    'user_name';

 2. drop USER 'user_name'@'localhost';
    flush privileges;
    CREATE USER 'user_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'user_name';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user_name'@'localhost'

 3. If the user is already created, the use the following command:

    ALTER USER 'user_name'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 
        'user_name';
```

Answer (score 6):

You are having issue with newly MySQL version that came with "caching_sha2_password" plugin, follow the below command to get it resolved.

```
DROP USER 'your_user_name'@'%';
CREATE USER 'your_user_name'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'your_user_password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_db_name.* TO 'your_user_name'@'%' identified by 'your_user_password';
```

Or you can just use the below command to keep your privileges as it is:

```
ALTER USER your_user_name IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password;
```

Comment: Hello what you mean by " your_db_name.* " on the third line what is that * represent for

Comment: The db name where user suppose to get the access. or you can simply use only last ALTER statement that will also resolve your issue. In ALTER you just need to pass your user name thats all

Comment: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON your_db_name.* TO 'your_user_name'@'%' identified by 'your_user_password';

Comment: Okay, you are facing the issue while connecting to DB right? Mean you are also specifying some DB name in a connection string, the same DB need to be added in place of your_db_name. hope you clear

Answer (score 6):

I did exactly the same issue using the dependency below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.44</version>
</dependency>
```

I just change to version 46 and everything works.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is better to update your "mysql-connector" lib package, so database can be still more safe.

I am using mysql of version 8.0.12. When I updated the mysql-connector-java to version 8.0.11, the problem was gone.

Comment: This is a great answer! I was using `5.1.44` with mysql 8. I used the latest version which is 8.0.19 and it worked!

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem on NetBeans when working with a ready-made project from [this Murach JSP book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1890774782).  The problem was caused by using the 5.1.23 Connector J with a MySQL 8.0.13 Database.  I needed to replace the old driver with a new one.  After downloading the Connector J, this took three steps.

How to replace NetBeans project Connector J:

1. Download the current Connector J from [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/8.0.html).  Then copy it in your OS.
2. In NetBeans, click on the Files tab which is next to the Projects tab.  Find the mysql-connector-java-5.1.23.jar or whatever old connector you have.  Delete this old connector.  Paste in the new Connector.
3. Click on the Projects tab.  Navigate to the Libraries folder.  Delete the old mysql connector.  Right click on the Libraries folder.  Select Add Jar / Folder.  Navigate to the location where you put the new connector, and select open.
4. In the Project tab, right click on the project.  Select Resolve Data Sources on the bottom of the popup menu.  Click on Add Connection.  At this point NetBeans skips forward and assumes you want to use the old connector.  Click the Back button to get back to the skipped window.  Remove the old connector, and add the new connector.  Click Next and Test Connection to make sure it works.

For video reference, I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nW13FmTdkjc) to be useful.  For IntelliJ IDEA, I found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlvLgP79PcQ&t=3s) to be useful.

Comment: I realize my answer is not entirely relevant.  I posted my NetBeans answer here because [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53531588/connecting-a-db-to-netbeans-first-time?noredirect=1#comment93953573_53531588) is marked as a duplicate to this question.

Answer (score 2):

If you can update your connector to a version, which supports the new authentication plugin of MySQL 8, then do that. If that is not an option for some reason, change the default authentication method of your database user to native.

Answer (score 0):

remove the connect .jar file if you added the multiple version connector jar file only add the connector jar file that match with your sql version.

Answer (score 0):

Another cause might be the fact that you're pointing to the wrong port.

Make sure you are actually pointing to the right SQL server. You may have a default installation of MySQL running on 3306 but you may actually be needing a different MySQL instance.

Check the ports and run some query against the db.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this error which is confusing. Eventually I find this is none of business for mysql java connector version, the error in fact is that I have set wrong datasource-user-name(this config: `spring.datasource.druid.username`).

0. The sprint boot error info is :

```
create connection error, 
url: jdbc:mysql://..amazonaws.com:3306/moe_grooming?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&allowMultiQueries=true&useSSL=false, errorCode 0, state null

3624 java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password
```

My Environment:

1. `MySQL Server 8.0.22`
2. mysql java  connector version

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <version>5.1.44</version>
</dependency>
```

3. The used password plugin of this user is `mysql_native_password`

Answer (score 0):

If you encounter this error `Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' cannot be loaded` by export or else. Because DBeaver still using MySQL binary version 5.

So you need to download MySQL binary version 8 from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ then extract it to some path for a new environment like the below image.

[image]

Then you need to set binary from here or on edit connection

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Setup

I was facing the issue with the docker image `MySQL Server 8.2.0`.
The microservice side was `Java 21`+ `SpringBoot 3.2.0`

As stated in many of these answers the `mysql-connector-j.VERSION` (former `mysql-connector-java`) has to fit the database version.
Therefore `<mysql-connector-j.version>8.2.0</mysql-connector-j.version>` was added in the `pom.xml`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
    <version>${mysql-connector-j.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

## Debugging

On database startup everything seemed smooth.
The init-SQL-script was processed sucessfully

```
[Note] [Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

Sample init.sql (for debugging):

```
-- creates the auth schema
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS auth;
CREATE USER 'authuser'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH 'caching_sha2_password' BY 'sampleAuthPassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON auth.* TO 'authuser'@'%';

SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
```

This should give you something alike this:

```
mysql-db  | User    Host
mysql-db  | authuser    %
mysql-db  | root    %
```

## Problem

Still the microservice failed connecting to the MySQL-Database with the `HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.`

```
auth-endpoint-1  | 2023-12-12T08:21:38.114Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
auth-endpoint-1  | 2023-12-12T08:21:39.365Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
auth-endpoint-1  |
auth-endpoint-1  | java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'auth'@'192.168.48.3' (using password: YES)
auth-endpoint-1  |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:130) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
auth-endpoint-1  |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
auth-endpoint-1  |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:815) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
auth-endpoint-1  |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:438) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
auth-endpoint-1  |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
auth-endpoint-1  |  at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:189) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.2.0.jar!/:8.2.0]
```

Three (3) attempts were fired by the SpringBoot-Service.
All attempts could be seen as single error lines in the DB.

So far so known ... . .

## Solution

Everyone here is right, that the versions of `MySQL` and `mysql-connector-j` have to match!

Additionally:

- For me it was irritating that the same error was published for using a wrong **user/password** combination.

After revision of

- `docker-compose.yml`
- DB -> `init.sql`
- SpringBoot -> `application.yml`

The error was fixed on fitting User/Password-Combination   ;-)