# Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' in Netbean

Tags: mysql

I am connecting MySQL - 8.0 with Netbean and get error: 
Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'. 
Any solution for this ?

[image]

Comment: nobody here can guess your code, please post it in your question

Comment: not from my code, its appear when i try to connect mySQL server from netbean. I was edited my question with a picture, pls help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching\_sha2\_password' issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387952/how-to-resolve-unable-to-load-authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-issu)

Comment: For all looking here for answers the first one with ALTER USER worked for me, it's here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50209363/3140614

Answer (score 2):

You should use MySQL Connector/J 8.0.9 or higher.

For Windows 7:

1. Create a new driver [new driver creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwaBf.jpg)
2. Select a new MySQL Connector/J 8.0.9 or higher [choosing new driver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAwFf.jpg) If you didn't install it during MySQL setup, you should do it first
3. Create a new connection using new driver [new connection creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbOsf.jpg)
4. Check an information, enter the password, change a value of the "zeroDateTimeBehavior" param to "CONVERT_TO_NULL", test the connection [check connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MC0Wr.jpg) If you have a "time zone" error, you should configure your MySQL time zone first

Comment: Your MySql server version and the Driver version should be same. It works for me on a maven project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find your `my.ini` (windows) or `my.cnf` (mac os) file and add the following line in order to change default authentication:

```
default_authentication_plugin=mysql_native_password
```

Comment: my my.ini file already has this setting. What else could be the problem though?.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do anything with your admin DB or user table. Here is a solution,
first of all, if you have already any connection which is unable to connect, delete it.
then download the drivers from this link 
https://jar-download.com/download-handling.php
after downloading the drivers extract them and cut-paste them in the following directory.
C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\ide\modules\ext\
After doing this all, create a new connection but change the drivers with the above drivers. Now test the connection.
It worked for me successfully and I hope it will work for you too.