# MySQL connection fails in netbeans while using mysql (Connector/Jdriver)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, netbeans

[image: MySQL Connection error]

While trying to connect to my mysql database in netbeans, I get the following error message:

> Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull using com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'.)

So I can't connect to the database.

Comment: Do you use a Macbook?

Comment: Can you provide whole error message with stack trace?

Comment: Which version of MySQL Connector/J and which version of NetBeans are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50387952/2985643), especially [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50433762/2985643) which links to [this information on authentication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html), which is relevant if you are using MySQL 8.0.4+.

Comment: using Server version: 8.0.12 MySQL Community Server - GPL

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle & mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar  to connect