# Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'. even when mysql-connector is up to date

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

```
Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'.
```

Getting this error.

Have this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.12</version>
</dependency>
```

(8.0.14 has the same error) and the version of mysql I try to connect to is 8.0.12.

How can I fix that error (without switching to mysql_native_password).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching\_sha2\_password' issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387952/how-to-resolve-unable-to-load-authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-issu)

Comment: Please check this link - https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/mysql-errors-unable-to-load-authentication-plugin-caching_sha2_password.304616/

Comment: @RameshSubramanian without switching to mysql_native_password

Comment: The last item in [release notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/8.0/en/news-8-0-14.html) is a fix to ChangeUser. Have you tried 8.0.14?

Comment: @danblack also doesn't work (same error)