# Could not get JDBC Connection nested exception SQLException Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc" />
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="root" />
</bean>
```

I have updated MySQL Connector/J to 8.0.14 but still getting the same error.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50433762/2464172
And other answers in the above link.

Comment: Post your source code, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command. It might solve.

sample username / password => student / pass123

```
ALTER USER 'student'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'pass123';
```

[How to resolve Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' issue(SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387952/how-to-resolve-unable-to-load-authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-issu)

If above doesn't work try to use MYSQL driver which supports MYSQL 8.

[MySQL and Java Versions They Support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-versions.html)

Comment: After using it, I am now getting "java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long" error which requires to downgrade MySQL .

Comment: The problem is bcz of mysql and mysql driver versions. Please update both versions properly. Try to search mysql driver version for u r present mysql version.

Answer (score 0):

Installed mysql 5.5 version and it worked fine with that.
Thanks for your help.