# How to fix error 'Unable to create injector' in Play Framework 2.7 when trying to connect to MySql db

Tags: mysql, database, playframework, configuration, playframework-2.0

I am working on Play 2.7 project for the first time. As I added some db config stuff for mysql db, I get error at the start saying: "CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:"

[1st part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhPQL.png)
[2nd part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tw7L.png)

and a lot of other lines

build.sbt :

```
   name := """playreview"""
   organization := "asis"
   version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
   lazy val playreview = (project in file("."))
   .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean)
   scalaVersion := "2.13.0"
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(guice, evolutions, javaJdbc)
   libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.41"
```

application.conf :

```
 play.db {
     config = "db"
     default = "default"
   }

 db {
     default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
     default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/playreviewdb?useSSL=false"
     default.username=root
     default.password="*****"
   }

   # db connections = ((physical_core_count * 2) + effective_spindle_count)
 fixedConnectionPool = 9

 database.dispatcher {
     executor = "thread-pool-executor"
     throughput = 1
     thread-pool-executor {
       fixed-pool-size = ${fixedConnectionPool}
     }
   }

 ebean.default = ["models.*"]
```

Comment: And you're sure your mySQL instance is running?  Make sure you've tested it by going to the terminal and typing: mysql -u root

Comment: Yes it is running. I also tried to connect to it via my other spring app and it worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resolve Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching\_sha2\_password' issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387952/how-to-resolve-unable-to-load-authentication-plugin-caching-sha2-password-issu)