# Connection Spring Boot-MySql : Public Key Retrieval is not allowed

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I ran one of my apps back in early June of this year with no problems.  After trying it again today, I get the following error in the console :

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed`

Any ideas on how to fix?

I've researched this but have found nothing specific to Spring Boot apps.

Settings in applications.properties :

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/

spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false&requireSSL=false&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = 


spring.jpa.show-sql = true 


spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update


spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy = org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed`

Comment: check this thread
`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379839/connection-java-mysql-public-key-retrieval-is-not-allowed`

Comment: Thanks.  I  tried adding `useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` but still does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 14):

use the following

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/payphone?useSSL=false&useJDBCComplaintTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
```

Answer (score 4):

Possible solutions :

1 - Check if the mysql uses port 3306 and it's alive.

2 - Make sure your mysql username and password is correct.

3 - If you are using Mysql 8 and above then you may check authentication plugin change form [this link](https://qiita.com/shaching/items/5fe3d5df691b4ec53084)

Comment: The steps here https://qiita.com/moonlightbox/items/5fe3d5df691b4ec53084 solved my problem. I was using mysql 8 with docker.Thanks