# keycloak standalone integration with mysql-innodb-cluster

Tags: mysql, jboss, wildfly, innodb, keycloak

Trying to get keycloak to work with mysql-innodb-cluster. I have configured the keycloak standalone.xml as per the documentation.

This is the datasource

```
            <datasource jndi-name="java:/jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS" pool-name="KeycloakDS" enabled="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://19.57.1.115:6446/keycloak?useSSL=false&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>15</max-pool-size>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>key</user-name>
                    <password>abababab</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                    <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                    <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                    <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
```

This is the drivers

```
            <drivers>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

I've also added module.xml for packaging mysql jdbc driver (I'm using latest version mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar)

The error I'm getting when I run keycloak is

```
10:45:23,155 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.LiquibaseJpaUpdaterProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Initializing database schema. Using changelog META-INF/jpa-changelog-master.xml
10:45:24,088 ERROR [org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.conn.DefaultLiquibaseConnectionProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) Change Set META-INF/jpa-changelog- 
1.0.0.Final.xml::1.0.0.Final-KEYCLOAK-5461::sthorger@redhat.com failed.  Error: Table 'APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES' already exists [Failed SQL: CREATE TABLE keycloak.APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES (APPLICATION_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL, ROLE_ID VARCHAR(36) NOT NULL)]
10:45:24,414 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to update database
10:45:24,446 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-2) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal
```

Any help in this regards would be very helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connection Java-MySql : Public Key Retrieval is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379839/connection-java-mysql-public-key-retrieval-is-not-allowed)

Comment: Unfortunately that did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I think the error "Error: Table 'APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES' already exists" you see is not the root cause. Keycloak uses [Liquibase](https://www.liquibase.org/) for database initialisation and upgrade management. Liquibase does not seem to support MySQL innodb cluster since it creates a table "DATABASECHANGELOG" [without a primary key](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1909). If you check your MySLQ log you will probably see the following log message at the first start of keycloak when it creates its database tables:

```
[ERROR] Plugin group_replication reported: 'Table DATABASECHANGELOG does not have any PRIMARY KEY. This is not compatible with Group Replication'
```

The table now exists on your database primary but has not been replicated to the other replication group members. If you then start Keycloak for a second time you will get error message "Table 'APPLICATION_DEFAULT_ROLES' already exists" you have seen.

You can work around this issue if you start with an empty database schema, create the DATABASECHANGELOG table with a primary key manually and then let Keycloak (that is Liquibase actually) create the rest of the tables.

You can use the following statement to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `DATABASECHANGELOG` (
  `ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `AUTHOR` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `FILENAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `DATEEXECUTED` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ORDEREXECUTED` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EXECTYPE` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `MD5SUM` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DESCRIPTION` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMENTS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TAG` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LIQUIBASE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONTEXTS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LABELS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DEPLOYMENT_ID` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`AUTHOR`,`FILENAME`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: thank you for the response...will try and let you know

Comment: @ChandraKanth did it work for you? Facing the same issue but this is not helping for me at least. Can you pls share your feedback?