# Could not create connection to database server via Docker

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, microservices

I have created a simple spring boot app to communicate with MYSQL via docker using the same network. Once I run `docker-compose up` command then following errors have occurred

> employee-jdbc-container | java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException:
> Could not create connection to database server. Attempted reconnect 3
> times. Giving up.
>
> employee-jdbc-container | Caused by:
> com.mysql.cj.exceptions.UnableToConnectException: Public Key Retrieval
> is not allowed

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"   
services:
  employee-mysql:
             image: employee-jdbc
             container_name: employee-jdbc-container
             ports:
             - "9090:9090"
             networks:
               - employee-mysql2    
             depends_on:
               - mysqldb
  mysqldb:
         image: mysql:8
         container_name: mysqldb
         ports:
         - "3306:3306"
         networks:
           - employee-mysql2
         environment:
           - MYSQL_USER=root
           - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
           - MYSQL_DATABASE=HR
networks:                     
    employee-mysql2:
```

**application.yml**

```
server:
  port: 9090

spring:
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/HR?createDatabaseIfNotExists=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"
    username: root
    password: root
    platform: mysql
    initialization-mode: always
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

I think the problem in the configuration file but have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Please try to connect to the database with a different tool, to see if it's working. If the db works, the issue is probably within in the application.yml.

Comment: Are you sure your DB is up, when connection is made? Did you try to repeat ```docker-compose up``` after short period? (it should restart your application while keep DB inact.)

Comment: Your error suggests, you need to update starting options - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379839/connection-java-mysql-public-key-retrieval-is-not-allowed

Comment: @GiantsGits yes.DB container is runing

Comment: @RatzzFatzz MYSQL has not been installed in my local machine. if there any other way to check it without installing it in the local machine

Comment: @NafazBenzema make sure mysql-client package is installed and then you can do the following: ```docker exec <container_name> mysql -uroot -p```. But in general, there different methods, which would also work. (access the containers bash and then mysql, etc.)

Comment: @RatzzFatzz should I have to install it explicitly. doesn't it contain with MYSQL image

Comment: @RatzzFatzz yes I can access MYSQL using bash. it is running properly. but the problem occurs when trying to communicate with spring boot and MySQL

Comment: Great, at least we now know, that it's definitely spring boot / java side

Comment: @NafazBenzema Did you try to update the starting options? If not, try to use this URL: ```"jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/HR?createDatabaseIfNotExists=true&autoReconnect=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false```

Comment: @RatzzFatzz " jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/HR?createDatabaseIfNotExists=true&autoReconnect=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false" . it does not give the solution. same errors are occured

Answer (score 2):

finally, I have found another way to run both containers without any issue.

**first set MySQL environment**

> docker pull mysql:8

then run the image as a container

```
docker container run -d --name mysql-db -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=<root_password> -e MYSQL_DATABASE=<database_name>
-e MYSQL_USER=<user> -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=<password>  mysql:8(image name with version)
```

**second set spring boot environment**

*application.yml*

```
server:
  port: 9090

spring:
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:mysql://mysql-db/<database_name>?createDatabaseIfNotExists=true&autoReconnect=true&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false"
    username: <username>
    password: <password>
    initialization-mode: always
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    tomcat:
      test-while-idle: true
      validation-query: SELECT 1
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
```

*Docker file*

```
FROM openjdk:11
COPY ./target/employee-mysql.jar employee-mysql.jar
EXPOSE <port number> (where your application is running)
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","employee-mysql.jar"]
```

build a docker image for spring boot app

> docker image build -t employee-jdbc .

run the employee-jdbc image as a container

```
docker container run -d --name employee-mysql -p 9090:9090 --link mysql-db:mysql(mysql is the image of mysql-db container) employee-jdbc(employee-jdbc is the image of employee-mysql container)
```