# Cannot run docker-compose.yml (throw image issues) in my Spring Boot App

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I have a problem about running docker-compose.yml in my Spring Boot app.
When I run this command (docker-compose up -d), I got an issue in image part.

I tried to handle with solving this issue but I couldn't do that.
How can I fix it?

Here is my issue shown below.

```
    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

Here is my project : [My Project](https://github.com/Rapter1990/SpringBootElk)

Here is my docker-compose.yml shown below.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.15.2
    user: root
    command: -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/:/etc/logstash/conf.d/
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.15.2
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./kibana/:/usr/share/kibana/config/
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    entrypoint: ["./bin/kibana", "--allow-root"]
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.15.2
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
  app:
    image: 'springbootelk:latest'
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: SpringBootElk
    depends_on:
      - db
      - logstash
    ports:
      - '8077:8077'
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/springbootexample?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=Turkey
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=springexample
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=111111
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update
  db:
    container_name: mysql-latest
    image: 'mysql:latest'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/mysql

# Volumes
volumes:
  db-data:
```

Comment: You aren't connecting to `localhost` but to `db`, which is the hostname.

Comment: @M.Deinum I edited my post.

Comment: There is no garantuee that MySQL is up and running when the app starts. The container could be started but MySQL not (the depends-on doesn't prevent that).

Comment: @M.Deinum I updated my post again. The previous issue was disappeared but I couldn't fix that issue.

Comment: @Alex I couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues, why it doesn't work.
First thing - your tests aren't set up properly. Application tries to connect to database in the `test` stage. But during the `test` stage there is no any running containers yet. You can set it up properly, or remove `MainApplicationTests` class from the test directory, or by switching off your tests execution, just by adding `-Dmaven.test.skip` in `Dockerfile` for the `mvnw package` command. After it your image will build properly.
Second thing, you need to allow public key retrieval for your application. To do that, you can add `allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true` to your jdbc url. You can read more about it here: [Connection Java - MySQL : Public Key Retrieval is not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379839/connection-java-mysql-public-key-retrieval-is-not-allowed).
These steps will allow your application to start (at least it will resolve database connectivity problems). But, I have found another issue. You set in your application configuration `context-path` equal to `/api`. Also you added `@RequestMapping("/api")` for your `PersonController`. And to access the list of persons, you will need to use the following url: `http://localhost:8077/api/api/persons`. Probably, it is not what you wanted. To fix it, you can remove it from any place.